# Why is this not legal in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

This doesn't work

```
public class Foo {
    private int X { get; }

    public Foo(string s) {
        int.TryParse(s, out X);
    }
}
```

but this works:

```
public class Foo {
    private int X { get; }

    public Foo(string s) {
        int x;
        int.TryParse(s, out x);
        X = x;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the two, since the `out` parameter doesn't need to be initialised. Why the property cannot be passed as an out parameter?

Comment: Doesn't your property need a `set`?

Comment: Because properties get internally rewritten to method calls `get_X()`. out params can only be variables or fields.

Comment: @WaiHaLee It's a new C# 6 feature. No, it does not need a `set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `out`, under the hood it's really a memory address that gets passed to the function that you call. A property is not a variable but a function and you cannot take its address so a property cannot be passed in place of an `out` parameter.

A member variable (or local variable) occupies memory and the compiler can take their address and pass it so it works with variables but not with properties.

Comment: thanks I see, but is there any way to pass the property by reference with a delegate for example?

Comment: @Nostradamus At some point you'll have to write `out X` inside _some_ function. You can try to hide this function deep inside delegates, etc. but at the end, when you finally actually make the call to `TryParse`, it'll need a local / member variable because `out` / `ref` parameters are really passed as a memory address and the compiler won't take the address of a property.

Answer (score 9):

I assume this is C# 6.0 because you have a `get`-only property.

It doesn't work because properties cannot be passed by reference. A function that takes a `ref int` or an `out int` parameter in C# is like a function that takes an `int&` in C++.

But an `int` property is *not* just an `int` at some address. A property can run any code it wants to in both the `get` and the `set`. And the language should not treat an auto-implemented property as special.

What if I wrote code like the following?

```
public class Foo {
    private int X {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }

    public Foo(string s) {
        int.TryParse(s, out X);
    }
}
```

There simply isn't any address of an `int` to pass into `TryParse`. The rules for whether the code is allowable are not permitted to look inside the `get` and `set` implementations.

Note that this works fine:

```
public class Foo {
    private int X;

    public Foo(string s) {
        int.TryParse(s, out X);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean C# 6.0 (or just C# 6 would be fine too). But `X = x;` doesn't assign to the property, it assigns directly to the property's backing field. If `X` can refer to either the property or the backing field depending on context, `int.TryParse(s, out X)` *could* have been made to work. It simply wasn't.

Comment: @hvd You're right, I was getting confused with ASP.NET 5. ;) "`X` can refer to either the property or the backing field depending on the context." - It *can't* refer to either; it always refers to the property.

Comment: Then how do you explain the fact that `X = x;` compiles? Does `X` have a private setter that's inaccessible outside of constructors? It doesn't, `X = x;` is really translated as a direct access to the backing field, at least according to Roslyn's documentation (but I'll double-check). Note that that same rule already applied to events: given `public event EventHandler X;`, `X` could refer either to the event's `add`/`remove` accessors, or to the event's backing field.

Comment: @hvd You're talking about how the calling of the setter is actually implemented. My statement that `X` is always referring to the property is true at a language level. But of course it isn't true in terms of the code that actually runs. I don't think we're disagreeing here...

Comment: I'm talking about how the property doesn't even *have* a setter. Not even a private one. Which means that the only way it could work is by referring directly to the backing field. I did check now, and that's exactly what's happening. But, actually, maybe you do have a point. There is no C# 6 language specification yet, as far as I am aware, and the current behaviour can be described in multiple different ways to achieve the same result. We can't know yet which description will end up being used by the language spec.

Comment: @hvd I won't be responding to any more of this because it seems like a very silly thing to argue about. :) I completely understand that the generated IL is just doing a single assignment to the underlying field and that the property has no setter. But I don't think it makes sense for `int X { get; }` and `int X { get { return 0; } }` to be treated differently in terms of the call `int.TryParse(str, out X);` - inside or outside of a constructor.

Comment: It doesn't seem silly at all to me. The whole question is "why doesn't C# do this", and your answer is basically that it can't. I'm trying to comment that it can, which seems extremely relevant to the question and to your answer to me. But yeah, let's drop it, because regardless of who's right or wrong, at least one of us (possibly you, possibly me, possibly both of us) seems to be unable to clearly explain to the other what is meant, and it won't help anyone else.